# How do we compare the effect of air pressure and the effect of temperature, on evaporation?

Tags: pressure, temperature, evaporation

Let's say we have some water with a boiling point of 90 Celcius in it's current environment; and with the same mass, same humidity, same bucket and all, we have some water with a boiling point of 100 Celcius in sea level.

My question is, which one would be fully vaporised first starting with the same temperature and with same equipment? In other words, how do we compare the effect of air pressure on evaporation speed and the effect of temperature on evaporation speed?